# I can't run any project in openDylan

Tags: dylan

I installed the software openDylan (windows 32 bit) but I can't run any program on it.
I created a project and when I compile the project I get the following error:

```
building targets: exe
don't know how to build <hello>library.obj
```

What do I do so I can pool run software projects?

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed a couple of things since the 2012.1 release and hope to do more for the 2013.1 release, but:

- Install Pelles C from http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/ if you
  haven't already.
- Inside the Open Dylan IDE, there's a settings dialog    that lets you
  choose a build script and you'll want to select the
  `x86-win32-pellesc-build.jam` file from within `C:\Program Files\Open Dylan\lib\`.
- Run the Open Dylan IDE from within a Pelles C command prompt. The IDE is `C:\Program Files\Open Dylan\bin\win32-environment.exe`.

I don't have Windows on the machine that I'm using at the moment, so I can't confirm the exact / correct paths, but hopefully I haven't made any terrible errors.

With that, things should work, including debugging.

We definitely need some improvements on Windows and we'd be happy to help you get going. (You can also chat with us on #dylan on Freenode IRC.)